# Unable to load DLL Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.x86.dll (Exception From HRESULT: 0x800707E)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, devexpress

#### Describe the bug

I am trying to edit connection string on my report using DevExpress winform report wizard 
[image: EditConnectionString]
when I click on next button I get this error
[image: Unable to load DLL]
When I try to install latest stable version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 1.1.3 I get two different error.
01-With Windows authentication 
[image: SNINative]

02-With Server authentication
[image: TdsParser]

Note: 
When running the app, all report works fine without any problems.

technical details

```
 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version: 2.0.0-preview4.20142.4  
 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI version: 2.0.0-preview1.20141.10  
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager version: 5.0.0-preview.4.20251.6  
 .NET target: Framework 4.7.2  
 SQL Server version: SQL Server 2019  
 Operating system: Windows 10 Version 2004  
 DevExpress 20.1.3  
 Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Preview Version 16.7.0 Preview 2.0
```

Update:
It is seems to be related to DevExpress version ,I downgrade to version 19.2.8 and all problems are gone.

Comment: Open solution Explorer and check Reference Tab.  Right click the SQLClient object and check location.  Either you have to add the reference or the reference is looking at the wrong folder.  There is a 32 bit and 64 bit and you may be running wrong version.  Also try a clean build (or delete the bin folder in project).  How can you have Windows 10 version 2004?

Comment: @jdweng Thanks ;it is seems to be related to DevExpress version ,I downgrade to version 19.2.8 and all problems are gone.

Comment: If this is a .NET Framework project (not .NET Core), uninstall Microsoft.Data.SqlClient from GAC. The Wizard should fallback to the System.Data.SqlClient library.